# Regular expression help to find space after a long string

Tags: python, regex

My code is as follow:

list = re.findall(("PROGRAM S\d\d"), contents

If I print the list I just print S51 but I want to take everything.

I want to findall everything like that "PROGRAM S51_Mix_Station". I know how to put the digits to find them but I don´t know how to find everything until the next space because usually after the last character there is an space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `"PROGRAM S\d\d\S*"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
list = re.findall(r"PROGRAM S\d\d[^ ]*", contents)
```

This would match `PROGRAM S` followed by two digits, then followed by any number of non space characters.  If you wanted to include all whitespace characters with spaces, then the @Wiktor comment would be better, i.e. use `PROGRAM S\d\d\S*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\w+`:

```
import re
s = "PROGRAM S51_Mix_Station"
new_data = re.findall('^PROGRAM\s\w+\_\w+_\w+', s)
final_data = new_data[0] if new_data else new_data
```

Output:

```
'PROGRAM S51_Mix_Station'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks. I find another solution.

lista = re.findall(("PROGRAM S\d\d\S+") To find any character after the digit as repetition.

Comment: But careful, you might want to use `\S*` at the end of the pattern, in case there are no characters after the final two digits.